# Price at Particular Date and Time

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, finance, alpha-vantage, excel-365

How to I query price at a particular **date and time** using Alphavantage API.

For eg: I tried this:

```
https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=^INFY&interval=1min&outputsize=compact&apikey=***********
```

However I want to pass both Date and Time and need the HIGH for that particular minute for that symbol.

I am using the Excel 365 Add-On but I can use Google Sheets as well.

Possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url will give you a json. You have then to parse it and then apply a formula to retrieve the max value and date/hour/minute it occurs. To parse the json, try with your own api key :

```
function getAllDataJSON(code) {
  var url = 'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol='+code+'&interval=1min&apikey='+YOURAPIKEY
  var data = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText())['Time Series (1min)']
  var resultat = []
  for (var elem in eval(data)){
    resultat.push([elem,eval(data[elem]['1. open']),eval(data[elem]['2. high']),eval(data[elem]['3. low']),eval(data[elem]['4. close']),eval(data[elem]['5. volume'])])
  }
  return resultat
}
```

If you want extended period, the answer will be a csv file

```
function getAllDataCSV(code){
  // last month : slice=year1month1 (by default) ... until slice=year2month12 (farthest month from today)
  // interval : 1min
  var url = 'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY_EXTENDED&slice=year1month1&symbol='+code+'&interval=1min&apikey='+apikey
  var csv = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  return Utilities.parseCsv(csv)
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mike. I will try it out and update this thread. 

I have a quick question. You are passing the Symbol. So I presume it will get Intraday data for today? Is it possible to pass the date, and return only the TIMESERIES for 
 that particular date in 'resultat'?

Comment: Since I am in GMT+2 (Paris summer -time), it gives me the intraday of yesterday. In fact, dcumentation says that `the API returns intraday time series of the equity specified, covering extended trading hours where applicable (e.g., 4:00am to 8:00pm Eastern Time for the US market)`.

Comment: I don't know if we could specify a date. However, it is possible to obtain data from 2 years ago. First, replace `TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY` by `TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY_EXTENDED` and add in the parameter the slice you nedd, i.e. `&slice=year1month1` for the most recent period (&slice=year1month1 until &slice=year2month12). Data are divided in 24 slices. You will obtain then a csv file (not a json file). Example `https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY_EXTENDED&symbol=INFY&interval=5min&slice=year1month1&apikey=yourapikey`

Comment: I have to try it out but I feel this will help me move forward. THANK YOU!!

Comment: Can we fetch last closing price ( e.g. Friday closing in case we want it on Saturday or Sunday) of say RELIANCE